# JS countdown clears text file

Tags: javascript, text, execute, countdown, zero

I tried many things but I can't seem to get things to work.

I use a JavaScript countdown that I found here: http://www.webmastersucks.com/countdown-date-time-javascript/

What I would like to do is whenever the timer get to zero it should clear a text file, however every time I try to add php it clears the file on page refresh and not when the timer gets to zero.

```
FinishMessage = "<?php file_put_contents('test.txt', ''); ?>";
```

I also tried to do a php include but that gives the same result.

What am I doing wrong? The FinishedMessage is inside a if statement so that should only execute if the time gets to zero right?

```
...
if (secs < 0) {
    document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = FinishMessage;
    return;
}
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how php works?

Comment: A little, guess it runs on page load no matter what right?

Comment: It's server side scripting. So php is done by the server first then sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

This is exectued when you serve the page, assigning it to a var won't change the execution time.

```
<?php file_put_contents('test.txt', ''); ?>
```

You should make an ajax request when your timer reaches 0, and process your file server side.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be that in the if statement you've said 'if secs is LESS than zero.'
You need to set it to if secs EQUALS zero.

simply like this

> if(secs == 0)

Hope that helps!

Comment: `==` or `===` is what your looking for in your answer